# Pymongo keeps refusing the connection at 27017

Tags: python, pymongo

I am trying to run a simple connection to pymongo but it keeps returning that the connection was refused

Here is what I tried:

```
>>>from pymongo import Connection
>>>connection = Connection('localhost',27017)
```

here is what I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo-2.0.1_-py2.7-linux i686.egg/pymongo/connection.py", line 348, in __init__
 self.__find_node()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo-2.0.1_-py2.7-linux- i686.egg/pymongo/connection.py", line 627, in __find_node
  raise AutoReconnect(', '.join(errors))
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 111]     Connection refused
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Removing `mongod.lock` inside `/var/lib/mongodb`

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

And then restarting the service should do it. For example, in my Ubuntu installation, restarting the server is something like this:

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

Comment: It should be `sudo service mongodb start` not `sudo service mongod start`

Comment: path should be `/var/lib/mongodb`.

Comment: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data on Windows thanks!

Comment: @jfleach that actually depends upon whether you're using the default package on Ubuntu (mongodb) or the official mongodb package. In the latter case, mongod and not mongodb is the service (daemon) name.

Comment: For me `sudo service mongod start` worked, not `sudo service mongodb start`

Comment: You need to issue the command **sudo service mongod start** to start the mongo server.

Comment: Did not worked for me

Comment: how do i run this inside a k8 pod?

Comment: On Macs with the Apple chip the file is probably located under `/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb`.

Answer (score 17):

If you found this page because you use Docker and you face the connection problem,
try to use in your client initialization the docker container name of the mongodb instead of the `localhost:27017` or `0.0.0.0:27017`

Steps to fix:

1. write `docker ps` in console
2. find the name of container (it's in the last column of the command output called `NAMES`
3. `MongoClient('mongodb://CONTAINER_NAME')`

PROFIT.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128397/how-to-connect-to-mongo-inside-a-docker-container-using-pymongo

Answer (score 14):

Just try following commands in given order :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

sudo mongod --repair

sudo service mongodb start

sudo service mongodb status
```

That's it now you could see following as output of last command:

`mongodb start/running, process 2796`

Answer (score 11):

For anyone who's having this problem on a remote server rather than the localhost, try enabling external interfaces:

- Go to the configuration file (ex. /etc/mongodb.conf)
- Find bind_ip=127.0.0.1
- Comment out that line with a # at the front
- Restart mongod

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you might not be running the MongoDB server. One thing that frequently trips me up is that if the server was shut down uncleanly, it will refuse to start up again until you remove the mongod.lock file from the data directory.

Answer (score 4):

Try following commands :

```
sudo service mongod start
sudo service mongod status
```

db.py

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
#mongo client is connected
client = MongoClient()
db     = client['db']
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than deleting mongod.lock, I'd recommend running 'mongod --repair'. (I figure it's better to go in through the front door whenever possible. And there may be other things that this catches as well, AFAIK.)

Comment: Fair enough. Though I don't recall size being a factor here. My answer's certainly valid for people working with smaller datasets.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers worked for me, as I am using *docker-compose* so this worked for me:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from my-mongo-server mongo unlink "/data/db/mongod.lock"
docker run --rm --volumes-from my-mongo-server mongo --repair
```

Replace `my-mongo-server` with your container name/id.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to connect from a server (other than your localhost), try checking if your mongo installation is complete :
you should have:
* /var/lib/mongodb file
* /var/log/mongodb file
* mongodb.service as service ( check by starting the service sudo service mongodb start )

If any of those fails, try reinstalling mongo ( [Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092353/failed-to-start-mongod-service-unit-mongod-service-not-found) )

This solved my problem.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have installed mongodb using `sudo apt install mongodb`

Answer (score 0):

For the newer versions(4.x) of MongoDb, you can try:

`sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock`

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

`sudo systemctl start mongod`

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, but for me i just had to stop mongod and then restart it and it worked fine without having to remove anything. PS : pymongo 2.7.2