# Connection refused to MongoDB errno 111

Tags: linux, mongodb, firewall, iptables

I have a Linode server running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and MongoDB instance (service is running and CAN connect locally) that I can't connect to from an outside source.

I have added these two rules to my IP tables, where < ip address > is the server I want to connect FROM (as outlined in this [MongoDB reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/)):

`iptables -A INPUT -s < ip-address > -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A OUTPUT -d < ip-address > -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

And I see the rule in my IP table allowing connections on 27017 to and from < ip address > however when I try to connect from , < ip address > to my mongo database using a command like this:

`mongo databasedomain/databasename -u username -p password`

I get this error:

`2014-07-22T23:54:03.093+0000 warning: Failed to connect to databaseserverip:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-07-22T23:54:03.094+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server < ip address >:27017 (databaseserverip), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed`

Any help is VERY APPRECIATED!!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you sure the other mongod is running? Can you connect to it locally?

Comment: mongod is running locally and yes, I can connect locally.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone!

Turns out that it was an iptable conflict.  Two rules listing the port open (which resulted in a closed port).

However, one of the comments by aka and another by manu2013 were problems that I would have run into, if not for the conflict.

So! Always remember to edit the `/etc/mongod.conf` file and set your `bind_ip = 0.0.0.0` in order to make connections externally.

Also, make sure that you don't have conflicting rules in your iptable for the port mongo wants (see [link on mongodb's site](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/) to set up your iptables properly).

Comment: Or just use 127.0.0.1 in the connectionString, instead of localhost, and connect internally...

Comment: Don't forget to make `sudo service mongod restart`

Comment: Don't do `bind_ip = 0.0.0.0` in production!!!! Or you will publicly expose your server…

Comment: @vinyll you should then restrict to specific ips using UFW (firewall)

Answer (score 52):

Try the following:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongodb restart
```

Comment: No luck. Still getting the connection failure. Thanks for the try.

Comment: Is your MongoD server bound to listen on all interfaces? 2.6.x is by default set to listen only on localhost. You can confirm this by "netstat -an | grep 27017" and it should show what all IP addresses the mongod is bound to.

Comment: Make sure that in your configuration file mongodb.conf, the bindIp setting (bind_ip for earlier versions) is set to listen to all interfaces by assigning the value 0.0.0.0 . By default, it only listens on localhost as its default value is 127.0.0.1 .

Comment: sometimes you need to remove the `mongodb-<port>.sock` file. in my case it is located on /tmp folder

Comment: @MatanTubul after trying everything and nothing worked, removing the file from /tmp solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 48):

These commands fixed the issue for me,

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo mongod --repair
sudo service mongod start
sudo service mongod status
```

If you are behind proxy, use:-
export http_proxy="http://username:password@company.com:port/"
export https_proxy="http://username:password@company.com:port/"

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24410282/4359237

Comment: If I run this command does it remove the data I have stored in the database

Comment: @devend It shouldn't as repair command runs repairDatabase command on all databases. repairDatabase: Checks and repairs errors and inconsistencies in data storage. repairDatabase is analogous to a fsck command for file systems. [Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/command/repairDatabase/#repairdatabase)

Answer (score 17):

For Ubuntu Server 15.04 and 16.04 you need execute only this command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mongodb
```

Answer (score 8):

I Didn't have a `/data/db` directory. I created one and gave a `chmod 777` permission and it worked for me

Answer (score 7):

For me, changing the ownership of /var/lib/mongodb and /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock to mongodb was the way to go.

Just do:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```

and then:

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

and then start or restart the mongodb server:

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

and check the status

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

Answer (score 3):

One other option is to just repair your database like so (note: db0 directory should be pre-created first):

```
mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --repairpath /var/lib/mongodb/db0
```

This is also an acceptable option in production environments...

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue.Make a directory in dbpath.In my case there wasn't a directory in /data/db .So i created one.Now its working.Make sure to give permission to that directory.

Answer (score 1):

In my case previous version was 3.2. I have upgraded to 3.6 but data files was not compatible to new version so I removed all data files as it was not usable for me and its works.

You can check logs using `/var/log/mongodb`

Comment: MongoDB should be successively upgraded to each major version until you reach the target. In this case, you need to upgrade to 3.4 first and you also need to configure featureCompatibilityVersion: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-standalone/

By doing so, you don't need to remove your data files, which is absolutely not an option if you have a large database.

Answer (score 1):

I follow this tutorial's instructions for installation

[How to Install MongoDB on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04)

I had the same mistake. Finally, I found out that I needed to set the port number

The default port number for the mongo command is 27017

But the default port number in mongo.conf is 29999

Answer (score 1):

This done the trick for me

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the port is open, MongoDB is currently only listening on the local address 127.0.0.1. To allow remote connections, add your server’s publicly-routable IP address to the **mongod.conf** file.

Open the MongoDB configuration file in your editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/mongodb.conf
```

Add your server’s IP address to the bindIP value:

```
...
logappend=true

bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,your_server_ip
#port = 27017

...
```

Note that now everybody who has the username and password can login to your DB and you want to avoid this by restrict the connection only for specific IP's. This can be done using Firewall (read about UFW service at Google). But in short this should be something like this:

```
sudo ufw allow from YOUR_IP to any port 27017
```