# Error in mongo start

Tags: mongodb

i am using mongo 3.0.2 version
suddenly, i have got a problem in mongodb. Till yesterday mongodb is running fine. but today when i start mongo then it gives the following error.

```
2015-04-29T10:57:47.732+0530 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to  127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-04-29T10:57:47.733+0530 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

i have checked on internet. **deleted the mongo lock file**. but didn't resolve the problem yet.

when i check the service is show waiting and after start it doen't start as

```
 service mongod status
 mongod stop/waiting
 sudo service mongod start
 mongod start/running, process 2520
 service mongod status
 mongod stop/waiting
```

and anyone help to solve it out and explain why this problem occur.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: do: echo $PATH in terminal, see if your path has mongodb's bin folder.

Comment: echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: i have reinstalled the mongodb but the problem still exist.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and I managed to start mongod following those steps

1) `mkdir data`

2) `cd data`

3) `mongod -dbpath .`

Comment: i've just faced the same error, and `mongod -dbpath .` solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command, it works fine:

```sh
sudo mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf --fork
```

Comment: Thanks, Vishnu it worked. Can you explain what happened and how it is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sudo mongo` to connect

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure if port 27017 is already opened and didn't used by any application. You can check it with `netstat` command

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether port already used or not?
Below attaching link of similar issue:
[Connection refused to MongoDB errno 111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899849/connection-refused-to-mongodb-errno-111)

Still problem persist then let me know.

Comment: i have changed the bind_ip but didn't help me

Comment: Just try to comment bind_ip

Comment: Before this have you changed any configuration files?? Last try from my side try to restart the service of MONGOD .

Comment: yesterday every thing was fine but suddenly today mongo is not connected i changed the configuration file only after the problem.. and i mention above in the problem when i start or restart service it gives and pid but not run when i check the status..

Answer (score 0):

check in the log file `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`. I also got the same issue but due to lack of disk space.

> ```
> exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**Delete** mongod.lock file in

data/db/mongod.lock

Then Run Again **It Works Fine** :)