# MongoDB no longer starts after updating

Tags: javascript, mongodb, npm

I recently updated my MongoDB server from 3.2 to 3.6 to fix some errors with naming. When I had my Mongo server as 3.2 it did work fine.

I downloaded the MongoDB 3.6 from https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community and installed it with the package manager (sudo dpkg -i mongodb-org-server_3.6.12_amd64.deb) and I have verified that the server did update with mongod --version.

As far as I know, starting the system works, but when I run mongo, or sudo mongo, it gives me the following output

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.22
connecting to: test
2019-05-14T13:28:09.049-0400 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2019-05-14T13:28:09.049-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

I'm not sure how I could fix the problem either, I have tried to restart the service and restarting the server it's running on (Ubuntu 16.04) and neither worked. Nothing I found online could help either so  if you know a possible solution, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection refused to MongoDB errno 111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899849/connection-refused-to-mongodb-errno-111)

Comment: Update your question with logs from the mongodb server. the error message given in the question talks only about the error when trying to connect to the server.

Comment: None of the solutions on the other one helped the one that did downgraded my mongodb to 2.6 which is the opposite of what I wanted. My `/var/log/mongodb` is empty and contains no logs to give. When I added a specific log path, the file was still empty after running `mongod`

Answer (score 0):

Before that, try with

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
mongod –repair
sudo service mongod start
```

Comment: I still get the same output

Comment: Try this before restart the service:
1) Remove .lock file
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock 
2) repair the mongodb
mongod –repair
3) start the mongod server
sudo service mongod start

Comment: After trying that, it still did not work. The output is the same as before aswell.