# Is it possible to connect to local MongoDB with flutter dart?

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, serversocket, flutter-dependencies

Everytime I try to connect to my local MongoDB, I keep getting this Exception:
SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 38748

Fun fact: the port in the exception increments by two after each try and is always wrong (I even started the server with the port throwing the exception next)

MongoDB server is running - I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017

Dependency is set -

dependencies:
  mongo_dart: ^0.3.5
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

```
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart' show Db, DbCollection;
class DBConnection {

  static DBConnection _instance;

  final String _host = "localhost";
  final String _port = "27017";
  final String _dbName = "debtservice";
  Db _db;

  static getInstance(){
    if(_instance == null) {
      _instance = DBConnection();
    }
    return _instance;
  }

  Future<Db> getConnection() async{
    if (_db == null){
      try {
        _db = Db(_getConnectionString());
        await _db.open();
      } catch(e){
        print(e);
      }
    }
    return _db;
  }

  _getConnectionString(){
    return "mongodb://$_host:$_port/$_dbName";
  }

  closeConnection() {
    _db.close();
  }

}
```

I already tried to run this code in plain dart and it runs.

Comment: check this answer it could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24941698/6709477

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Errno 111 is solved, but I got a 113 now :c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58847208/14207423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the problem now...

I had to take the Wireless LAN-Adapter IP of the my home device and start the mongodb with --bind_ip -ip-. The ip must also be provided in the connection string.

Still Thanks to MichaelM.

Answer (score 0):

Your `_host` won't be localhost when running on a device or in an emulator - you'll need to specify the actual IP address or network host name of the computer MongoDB is running on.

Comment: I encountered the same problem when I used flutter with mongoDb, even i changed localhost to wifi ip address 192.168.1.1
see the ipconfig :  
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.4
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Update mongo config file

```
 sudo nano  /etc/mongod.conf

 bindIp:127.0.0.1 ##### replace this line with below 

 bindIP:0.0.0.0  ####
```

After changing also, check the status of MongoDB

```
 sudo service mongod status
```

Now MongoDB works perfectly with flutter.