# Local Parse Server with Flutter causes error 111

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

I have a local Parse Server installed on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with:

> npm install -g --save --save-exact parse-server@4.2.0

Everything works with it using a locally installed Parse dashboard.

Running a Flutter app, however,produces an error:

> DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 60050

The local Parse Server ins started with:

> mongodb-runner start

> parse-server parse-server-config.json --cloud ~/main.js

The config is taken from a JSON file:

```
{
  "appName": "kayman",
  "databaseURI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/parsedb",
  "appId": "test",
  "javascriptKey": "test",
  "masterKey": "test",
  "serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
  "publicServerURL": "http://0.0.0.0:1337/parse",
  "port": 1337
}
```

SDK initialisation:

```
_parse = await Parse().initialize(
      serverConfig.appId,
      serverConfig.serverUrl,
      autoSendSessionId: true,
      debug: config.debug,
      coreStore: _coreStore,
      clientKey: serverConfig.clientId,
    );
```

config is from this section of a JSON file:

```
  "test": {
    "applicationId": "test",
    "clientId": "test",
    "restId": "test",
    "serverUrl": "http://localhost:1337/parse/"
  },
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989299/is-it-possible-to-connect-to-local-mongodb-with-flutter-dart) seems relevant, but I cannot find a mongodb.conf file anywhere.  The only reference to mongo I can find is in *~/.mongodb*, but that does not appear to contain a config file.

Can anyone advise how to fix this?

Comment: Could you share how you are starting parse server and how you are initializing the flutter sdk?

Comment: @Davi apologies for delayed response.  I have updated the question in response to your comment