# pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: mongodb, dns, localhost, pymongo

pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

When I try to insert data into mongodb, the error appears.

mongodb service is already started.

I can't open 'localhost' only on Safari, can open it on Chrome.(can open '127.0.0.1' on both).

my hosts  '127.0.0.1     localhost'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pymongo keeps refusing the connection at 27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744147/pymongo-keeps-refusing-the-connection-at-27017)

Comment: tried those, don't work:-(

Comment: Could you paste your Python code that triggers the error ?

Comment: already solved :-)  changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 in python code, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pymongo configuration error. Make sure dnspython module is installed:

```
pip install dnspython
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you recently upgrade to pymongo 4?

If yes, the missing configuration option `directConnection` in the connection-URI might be the Problem, since it defaults now to `False` instead of `None`.
Try `directConnection=true`.

The Behaviour changed here (see [migration guide](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrate-to-pymongo4.html#directconnection-defaults-to-false))

Answer (score -1):

I had to specify at the first argument in my connection string: "mongodb+srv":

Comment: I didn't downvote the question. It's really not me.