# Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I follow all the steps mention in MongoDB installation [documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) for `Ubuntu 16.04`.

**Steps 1:**

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
```

**Steps 2:**

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
```

**Steps 3:**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Steps 4:**

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

**Steps 5:**

```
sudo service mongod start
```

when I started MongoDB got an error as:

> **Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.**

Comment: I has the same problem and the following answer was the only thing that worked for me: [https://askubuntu.com/a/842599](https://askubuntu.com/a/842599)

Answer (score 136):

Most probably unit mongodb.service is masked. Use following command to unmask it.

`sudo systemctl unmask mongod`

and re-run

`sudo service mongod start`

Comment: returns: `Unit mongodb.service does not exist, proceeding anyway.`

Comment: @alper you need to start mongod service `sudo service mongod start`

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik even after using the above two commands the error is still the same as mentioned in the question

Comment: I cannot do `sudo service mongod start` since it also gives the following error: `Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.` @Jehanzeb.Malik

Comment: an important typo caused this answer to not work. please correct it. the proper unit name in Ubuntu is `mongod` not `mongodb`.  so the right command to unmask it would be: `sudo systemctl unmask mongod`. thank you for your attention.

Comment: For whatever reason, I had to say `mongodb` instead of `mongod` on Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18 it is mongodb and not mongod.

Comment: `mongodb` names are used in the outdated Ubuntu package, the official one uses `mongod` (for services, config etc). If you have `/etc/mongodb.conf`, most likely you have to uninstall the old package and install the official up-to-date one (similarly to what CodeGench has suggested, see my comment there too). If you have some date to save/migrate, take extra actoins to do so

Comment: That's confusing

Answer (score 73):

Please follow the below steps, it should work.

1 - Uninstall current installation completely

Source - [official instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#uninstall-mongodb-community-edition)

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

Remove Packages

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

Remove the folders

```
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

2 - Reinstall as described on official site, I will just write down the all steps. [enter link description here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition)

Import the public key

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
```

Create a list file for Ubuntu 16.04

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
```

update the list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the latest package

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

3 - Now it should work, please try below command

```
sudo service mongod start
```

and check the status

```
mongo
```

it should appear the mongo shell

Comment: For future readers who re-installed to no avail, this [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/770133/751635) is a better solution. It is unclear what the difference of this answer and OP's attempt as both point to same instructions link.

Comment: It would be nice if @Parfait's comment was incorporated into the answer. Saved me an incredible amount of time.

Comment: It works, I think the problem was that I did not install for the right ubuntu version (check it with `lsb_release -a`)

Comment: 2021 solution! Thanks bud

Comment: in my case, I installed the wrong unofficial packages from Ubuntu (`sudo apt install mongodb-server`). To remove those, I had to slightly modify the first 2 steps: `sudo service mongodb stop` and then `sudo apt-get purge mongodb*`

Comment: 2022 solution as well

Comment: Getting "Failed to enable unit: Unit file mongod.service does not exist." after I run the 1st command

Comment: @SantanuBiswas probably Mongodb is not running on your system. You can skip the first command.

Answer (score 50):

You are missing a 'b' I think?

```
sudo service mongod start
```

should be

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

I think this is the case?

Comment: after running "sudo systemctl unmask mongodb" its working :)

Comment: On ubuntu 18.04 if you installed from the system repo, then it's `mongodb` instead of `mongod`

Comment: ...and that installation from Ubuntu system repo is not recommended by official Mongo docs, it's quite outdated for now

Comment: there is no such things as mongodb - the things that get installed is a demon and its name is `mongod`

Comment: Ahah, thanks dude!

Answer (score 42):

**Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found**

If you are following the official doc and are coming across with the error above that means **mongod.service** is not enabled yet on you machine (I am talking about Ubuntu 16.04). You need to do that using following command

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod.service
```

Now you can start **mongodb** using the following command

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Comment: Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory :(

Comment: This worked even though `systemctl list-unit-files --type=service` said `mongod` was already enabled. Strange.

Comment: Getting "Failed to enable unit: Unit file mongod.service does not exist." after I run the 1st command

Answer (score 14):

**[Solution]**

Just type

```
sudo mongod
```

It will work.

Comment: if `Failed to enable unit: Unit file mongod.service does not exist.` this woulndn't help   only if perm  deny for `mongo`!

Comment: @JobinMathew, Worked fine in 18.4 LTS

Comment: Works for 16.04

Comment: Works for 20.04 to

Comment: Yeah but this doesn't run it as a daemon does it, bit useless for servers

Answer (score 10):

#### Case with me

Worked fine after the install; this problem occurred after I rebooted.

#### What worked for me is

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mongodb 
sudo mkdir /var/log/mongodb 
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb 
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
```

After running the above commands open a new terminal and run:

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

and run the mongo shell to check:

```
mongo
```

#### Note

> If this problem occurs again (as with me every time I reboot), make it as a shell script to be run at startup.

#### Permanent solution (shell script at startup)

**Step 1:**

Make a file in the `/etc/init.d` directory

```
sudo gedit /etc/init.d/custom-mongo-fix.sh
```

**Step 2:**

Put below code in the file you just opened in **Step 1**

```
#!/bin/bash

# mongodb fix
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mongodb 
sudo mkdir /var/log/mongodb 
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb 
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
```

**Step 3:**

After the next boot you can normally start the `mongod` server by:

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

**Explanation:** `mongodb` requires the above two folders with `owner` as `mongodb`. When we shutdown/reboot, one or both of them gets removed. So, we need to create them and change their ownership.

Edit: I was using [Stacer](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-stacer-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux-desktop)'s cleaning tool before every shutdown. This also removes log files and folders. And hence, the error at every startup. Now I unselect the mongodb option and then clean.

Namaste.

Comment: This is the only thing worked. Thanks man, you saved the day, really a Genius

Answer (score 8):

```bash
service mongodb start
service mongodb status
```

the status is active when I started using above command

Answer (score 8):

For Ubuntu 16.04.5, it is noticed that MongoDB installations does not auto enable the mongod.service file after installation in my case after I have installed on several servers, so we need to enable it like below:

Issue below to check whether mongod is enabled

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type=service
```

If it shows as "disabled", then you need to enable it.

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod.service
```

If we want to see whether mongod.service file exists in case this file is missing, check in

```
ls /lib/systemd/system
```

You will see a file

```
/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service
```

Comment: And if it's missing?

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me while adding users in admin db.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

is recommended from the official mongo website, but did not help.

If you get

> Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

While executing

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

run `journalctl -xe` and if the issue is

```
Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
```

Then run `sudo mongod` --> `mongo`
This will fix the issue and if you want to run with `systemctl`, then terminate the windows for mongod and mongo and run

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

and then `mongo`

Comment: Ran `journalctl -xe` and guess what? The problem was that the disk was full.

Answer (score 6):

None of the 30+ existing answers helped me, because my service file was actually missing, not masked or disabled. Re-installing wasn't creating it either for some reason. Solution:

```
cd /lib/systemd/system
sudo touch mongodb.service
# Copy and paste text to go into service file from snippet below horizontal rule
sudo nano mongodb.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start mongodb
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

---

```
[Unit]
Description=An object/document-oriented database
Documentation=man:mongod(1)
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You should check that /etc/mongod.conf is actually the location of your conf file, it may be /etc/mongodb.conf instead.

As for how your service file may have gone missing in the first place. I managed to break it by uninstalling 3.0.15, trying and failing to install 5.* due to ubuntu 16 not being able to run it since some dependencies clashed, then re-installing 3.0.15 again.

Answer (score 5):

Just try with this command:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

Answer (score 5):

You can repair

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
$ mongod --repair
$ sudo service mongodb start
```

For Stop

```
$ sudo service mongodb stop
```

For Restart-

```
$ sudo service mongodb restart
```

For Status-

```
$ sudo service mongodb status
```

Answer (score 5):

As per [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/):

Run this command to reload the daemon:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

After this you need to restart the mongod service:

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

To verify that MongoDB has started, run:

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

To ensure that MongoDB will start following a system reboot, run:

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

Answer (score 3):

May be you are using a wrong version of mongodb list file. I faced this problem but it's my mistake when not selecting the right list file for Ubuntu 16.04. The default selected is for Ubuntu 14.04 and it's the reason for my error: "Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found."
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following steps helped me solve the problem of not being able to start mongodb on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS

Step 1: First, remove MongoDB from previous if installed:

`sudo apt remove --autoremove mongodb-org`

Step 2: Remove any mongodb repo list files:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb*.list
sudo apt update
```

Step 3: Import the public key used by the package management system:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
```

Step 4: Create a list file for MongoDB:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
```

Step 5: Reload local package database:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 6: Install the MongoDB packages:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Step 7: Start MongoDB:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Step 8: Begin using MongoDB:

```
mongo
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases for some security reasons the unit would be marked as ***masked***. This state is much stronger than being disabled in which you cannot even start the service manually.

to check this, run the following command:

```sh
    systemctl list-unit-files | grep mongod
```

if you find out something like this:

```
    mongod.service                         masked
```

then you can unmask the unit by:

```sh
    sudo systemctl unmask mongod
```

then you may want to start the service:

```sh
    sudo systemctl start mongod
```

and to enable auto-start during system boot:

```sh
    sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

However if mongodb did not start again or was not masked at all, you have the option to reinstall it this way:

```sh
    sudo apt-get --purge mongo*
    sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

thanks to @jehanzeb-malik

Comment: I will add precision for those who visit this page in 2021 and above: instead of `mongod`, use `mongodb`.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error for a long while, tried almost all installation isntruciton on google but could not find te answer...

I followed the instructions from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ but keep getting the error  Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found

I firstly installed using: sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Then noticed that wher I run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
0 to upgrade, 4 to newly install, 0 to remove and 46 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/40.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 178 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-shell.
(Reading database ... 379307 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-shell_4.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-shell (4.0.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-mongos.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_4.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (4.0.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_4.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (4.0.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org_4.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org (4.0.3) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-shell (4.0.3) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-mongos (4.0.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-tools (4.0.3) ...
Setting up mongodb-org (4.0.3) ...


$ mongod --version
db version v2.6.12
2018-10-26T12:03:12.362+0200 git version: d73c92b1c85703828b55c2916a5dd4ad46535f6a
```

The db version was 2.6.12 instead of the latest one 4.0.3.
So make sure you dont have  mongodb-org-server already installed, if yes, then make sure you uupdate it to your target version (as indicated @https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ -> Step 4 - Install a specific release of MongoDB.)

target_version = 4.0.3

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=target_version mongodb-org-server=target_version mongodb-org-shell=target_version mongodb-org-mongos=target_version mongodb-org-tools=target_version

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=4.0.3 mongodb-org-server=4.0.3 mongodb-org-shell=4.0.3 mongodb-org-mongos=4.0.3 mongodb-org-tools=4.0.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mongodb-org-server
1 to upgrade, 4 to newly install, 0 to remove and 45 not to upgrade.
Need to get 15.7 MB/55.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 217 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org-server amd64 4.0.3 [15.7 MB]
Fetched 15.7 MB in 2s (6,289 kB/s)                 
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-shell.
(Reading database ... 379306 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-shell_4.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-shell (4.0.3) ...
**Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_4.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongod, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: old mongodb-org-server package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 5
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg: ... it looks like that went OK
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (4.0.3) over (2.6.12) ...**
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-mongos.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_4.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (4.0.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_4.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (4.0.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org_4.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org (4.0.3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-shell (4.0.3) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-mongos (4.0.3) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-tools (4.0.3) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-server (4.0.3) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/mongod.conf ...
Setting up mongodb-org (4.0.3) ...
```

and after doing this its all working for me :D

Answer (score 2):

Well.... My answer may be considered naive but in fact it has been the only way MongoDB has work in my case, Ubuntu 19.10. I tried to run the commands from the most voted comments and none worked, when running:

```
mongod --repair
```

I got this alert:

[image: The first time I used MongoDB that error appeared]

With some research I found out that running the DB in another port could be a solution, then:

```
mongod --port 27018
```

And it works great for me every time. Long answer but wanted to give context before giving such a simple solution.

(If I'm doing it wrong or doesn't seem logical, plz tell me! Relevant for me)

Answer (score 2):

Do not remove your db if you already have some data you found useful. Just run the command below and you're good.

```
sudo systemctl restart mongodb.service
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem of not being able to start mongodb on ubuntu 16.04
1) look at mongodb log file 
[image]

2) we find that the error is due to "Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017"

3) Look at the permission of file /tmp/mongdb-27017.lock
and find that the owner is root instead of mongodb

4) Delete the /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock file manually and use the command
"sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb*"

5) Start the service with systemcl and use netstat to check whther mongdob has been started on port 27017

[image]

Credit: https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-failed-to-unlink-socket-file-tmpmongodb-27017/
https://hevodata.com/blog/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this on my parrot os and this is how I solved it.

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the below commands. This has worked for me.

1. Uninstall your mongo completely from your system:

   ```
   sudo service mongod stop
   sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org
   sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
   sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
   ```
2. Now reinstall mongodb using following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install -y mongodb**
   ```

   **Note:** The database server is automatically started after installation.
3. Next, let's verify that the server is running and works correctly.

   ```
   sudo systemctl status mongodb
   ```

   You'll see this output:

   ```
   mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-05-26 07:48:04 UTC; 2min 17s ago
   Docs: man:mongod(1)
   Main PID: 2312 (mongod)
   Tasks: 23 (limit: 1153)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongodb.service
      └─2312 /usr/bin/mongod --unixSocketPrefix=/run/mongodb --config /etc/mongodb.conf**
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For those that run into this and end up on this answer, as I did, where they got this error during uninstall orupgrade and Ubuntu keeps failing to *uninstall* the previous because the service doesn't exist this one line will get you past that and allow the uninstall or upgrade to continue.

```
sudo touch /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me on ubuntu 20.04: In my case, mongod.service file was locked so it was giving me the same error.
To resolve the issue:-
Step 1: Use following command to check if the mongod.service is present there

```
cd /usr/lib/systemd/system
ls
```

Step 2: If the file is present there then Run the following command to unlock the file mongod.service

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service -R
```

Step 3: Now run the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start mongod
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

Answer (score 1):

For `Ubuntu`, if you have old mongodb installed (e.g 3.x).

**Then you might need to:**

- Remove old mongodb first.
- Remove old data, **WARNING**: this may cause data lose.
  e.g `sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb`
- Remove init script.
  e.g `sudo rm /etc/init.d/mongodb`
- Then re-install new mongodb, (e.g 4.x)
  Refer: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/
- Then start with `sudo service mongod start`.
- Then check status with `sudo service mongod status`.

**Tips:**

- Don't use `sudo service mongodb start`, there is an extra `b`, that's for old mongodb, that's why we do `sudo rm /etc/init.d/mongodb`.
- Backup your old data before remove it.

Comment: This is the issue I had. At some point I had installed mongodb the one that came bundled with ubuntu and apparently hadn't removed it completely. That's why my new installation wouldn't start. Removing the old files and reinstalling worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Ubuntu or any other OS, won't work proparly for the system files if you have closed rootlogin. That is right. Even when you enter the root on filesystem. I know it seems not logical but it is all about 1 and 0's here.

Even I have su -
or
`ssh root@934.2349.234243` (random IP, won't expose myself here:))

Still it didn't start!

```
"Failed to restart mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service not found."
```

Then...

You need to activate root login. You can download cyberduck or any file explorer to quickly find the file .

go to:
/etc/ssh/

if you couldn't go with a software tool, you can use for the step above:
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
then press ctrl-c
write to console for saving it
:wq

Change this file called sshd_config:
/etc/ssh/sshd_config

Edit to line to yes:
PermitRootLogin yes

REBOOT VPS

then write

```
sudo systemctl restart mongodb
```

Voila!

if that didn't help either because your VPS initiates services just before on the root, you should reinstall the VPS maybe

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question, if it's a permission issue then it should give him an error message like: `Failed to restart mongod.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status mongod.service' for details.`

Comment: Yes, it is a permission issue or VPS start up issue issuing services

Answer (score 0):

Note that if using the Windows Subsystem for Linux, systemd isn't supported and therefore commands like `systemctl` won't work:

> Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

See [Blockers for systemd? #994](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/994) on GitHub, Microsoft/WSL.

The mongo server can still be started manual via `mondgod` for development of course.

Answer (score 0):

The second step of mongo installation is

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
```

Instead of this command do it manually

1. `cd /etc/apt/`
2. `nano sources.list`
3. Write it  `deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse`

And save the file,

Continue all process as in installation docs

It works for me:

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `sudo systemctl start mongod`  and to check whether its running use `sudo systemctl status mongod`

Answer (score 0):

> sudo systemctl unmask mongod

The above command worked for me!

> sudo service mongod start

Try starting the service it after unmasking it

> sudo systemctl status mongod

Check the status using the above command or simply start the mongodb server using mongo command, I hope it works.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 20.04
And i had the same problem.

Finally found a working answer [here](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-packages-have-unmet-dependencies-on-18-04-upon-mongodb-install/)

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongo-tools
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongodb-server-core

sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-server mongodb-server-core mongodb-clients
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then reinstall via the official [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/).

Though i'd might share.
Enjoy.

Comment: Will this delete the database?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation of "Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found", followed by "exception in initAndList NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found"

My solution was first to set the path to the config file which had the custom database location instead of "data/db":

```
mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
```

Then I enabled and started the service with

```
sudo systemctl enable mongodb.service
```

Please not that even with mongod, I had to add 'b' because of the version am currently using. But the root daemon stays the same

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error too .. my error is unmet dependencies `/var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.4.2_amd64.deb` and I ran this:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.4.2_amd64.deb
```

and it worked

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb status
```

or:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb start
```