# mongo refusing connection on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mongodb

Ubuntu 16.04

console output for running `mongo` on the terminal:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-03-27T18:23:41.006+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-03-27T18:23:41.006+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Try to use port number mongo --port 27020

Comment: Did you run `mondodb` server?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48871898/5407898) by [@CodeGench](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5203370/codegench) helped resolve my problems. Before doing it, I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling and all sorts of things which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

User This Command

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Then

```
mongo
```