# Mongo fails to start after Xenial upgrade

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I've just completed upgrading my DigitalOcean droplet from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, but now I'm having trouble starting mongodb. This is the error I receive when trying to start the service:

```
# systemctl status mongod.service
● mongod.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mongod; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-02-16 12:49:28 EST; 17s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3800 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mongod start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 16 12:49:28 anthony-calandra mongod[3800]: Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
Feb 16 12:49:28 anthony-calandra mongod[3800]: utility, e.g. service mongod start
Feb 16 12:49:28 anthony-calandra mongod[3800]: initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connec
Feb 16 12:49:28 anthony-calandra mongod[3800]: Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Feb 16 12:49:28 anthony-calandra mongod[3800]: Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mongod
Feb 16 12:49:28 anthony-calandra mongod[3800]: start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connecti
Feb 16 12:49:28 anthony-calandra systemd[1]: mongod.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 16 12:49:28 anthony-calandra systemd[1]: Failed to start mongod.service.
Feb 16 12:49:28 anthony-calandra systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 16 12:49:28 anthony-calandra systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

If you need any more information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue. I had a strange installation of mongo so instead I removed it:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

Then I followed this tutorial to install the latest: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04

I then ran into the error message: "Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found". Turns out the service was disabled so I followed this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53553652/3229983.

Service looked good:

```
# sudo systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-02-16 13:08:19 EST; 7s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 5711 (mongod)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─5711 /usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

Feb 16 13:08:19 anthony-calandra systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
```

And now my webapp runs.