# Not able to start mongoDB services

Tags: mongodb, wiki.js

I have installed mongodb but when trying to start mongodb.service

but it shows the error
Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service not found.

what might be the reason how to resolve this.
Thanks!!!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092353/failed-to-start-mongod-service-unit-mongod-service-not-found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092353/failed-to-start-mongod-service-unit-mongod-service-not-found)