# Mongod.service not found => Pop from an empty deque => Authentication failed

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu, pymongo

---

## The Problem

**I'm getting started with `MongoDB` on `Python`, I have a `Ubuntu` machine in my `local network` and `MongoDB` is installed there. When I try to connect with database using `Python` from `Mac` it throughs me an error. I searched about it and found out there is a `.service` called `mongod.service` that needs to be started along with `mongodb.service`. But when I try to start the `mongod.service` the it says the `.service` doesn't even exist. I tried both with IP and mongodb url, nothing works.**

## Ubuntu Terminal

```
$ sudo service mongod start
$ Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
$ sudo systemctl start mongod
$ Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
```

---

## DataBase Link (a)

```
mongodb://user:password@192.168.0.106/database
```

## Python Script (a)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://user:password@192.168.0.106/database')

db = client['database']

collection = db['collection']

json = dict(message='hello world', token=0)

collection.insert_one(json)
```

## macOS Terminal (a)

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 192.168.0.106:27017: [Errno 61] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 60e140982a43032aef0dd634, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('192.168.0.106', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('192.168.0.106:27017: [Errno 61] Connection refused')>]>
```

---

## DataBase Link (b)

```
mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.h9fmz.mongodb.net/database?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

## Python Script (b)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.h9fmz.mongodb.net/database?retryWrites=true&w=majority')

db = client['database']

collection = db['collection']

json = dict(message='hello world', token=0)

collection.insert_one(json)
```

## macOS Terminal (b)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1278, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.sockets.popleft()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
.....
.....
.....
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
```

---

## Note That

- **I'm providing the correct username and password for the database.**
- **I'm using a machine on my local network, which is not a live server.**
- **I've also tried the following commands but they did not solve anything.**

## Ubuntu Terminal

```
$ mongod --auth --port 27017
$ mongod --port 27017
$ sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
$ sudo mongod --repair
```

---

Comment: Are you able to connect with `mongodb` via `mongo shell`?

Comment: Yes, I can do that

Comment: Try this: `sudo systemctl unmask mongod` then try to re run: `sudo service mongod start`

Comment: I recommend u to use MongoDBCompass, can be url error, if u can connect from MongoCompass, isnt firewall or config error

Answer (score 3):

For accessing mongodb from another machine in local network. You will need to check the following:

1. There is no firewall restriction in the server machine or client machine. In case there is a firewall, you will need to add rule exceptions to allow this port to be accessible. Both incoming and outgoing. ([Ubuntu firewall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-firewall))
2. You will have to add bindIp config to the mongodb config in server machine. Refer to docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp). You will need to add something like this:

   ```
   net:
      bindIp: 0.0.0.0
      port: 27017
   ```
3. Make sure you are able to connect using this ip: 192.168.0.106(server in local network) from the server machine itself. This will make sure the server is listening in this ip.

`$ Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.`

The solution for this error could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092353/failed-to-start-mongod-service-unit-mongod-service-not-found)

The mongo atlas error might be due to the following reasons:

1. You will have to create an database user in order to connect to mongodb.
   you can find it under the left panel -> `Database access` -> `Add user`
2. This will be because of a mismatch with username and password. In case you have any special characters in your password you will have to [url encode](https://www.urlencoder.org/) them.