# pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I am trying to use docker-compose with my django-rest app. 
When I run it myself `python manage.py runserver` it works well.

If I am trying to use docker-compose `sudo docker-compose up` it also runs the server but when I open the page in the browser I get an error.

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I already have db, so I am just using this lines in `settings.py`

```
MONGODB_DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "name": 'api',
        "host": 'localhost',
       "port": 27017
    },
}
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  mongo:
    image: mongo
```

Already tried this:

[Pymongo keeps refusing the connection at 27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744147/pymongo-keeps-refusing-the-connection-at-27017)

Answer (score 5):

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each
>   container for a service joins the default network and is both
>   reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
>   them at a hostname identical to the container name.

According to the `docker-compose.yaml` file, `mongo` container is accessible on `mongo:27017` from `web` container, so `settings.py` should be changed to:

```
MONGODB_DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "name": 'api',
        "host": 'mongo',
       "port": 27017
    },
}
```

Comment: tried to replace localhost to mongo, but still get the same error

Comment: Does mongodb work on host or in a container from above `docker-compose` file?

Comment: as I understand it works in a container from `docker-compose`

Comment: Shouldn't you also link `mongo` from `web` in order to access the hostname?

Comment: Here it worked well. But you need to put the name of your container mongo.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The issue was that I used the wrong port forwarding and had an old container which was stopped but not removed.

I restarted the old container. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the other answers the problem is related to the `mongo` container name in the `docker-compose.yml` file so the Django settings must be changed to find the correct database host.

In later versions Djongo changed the `DATABASE` options in the `settings.py`. This will result in the following new `settings.py` part:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'api',
        'CLIENT': {
            'host': 'mongo',
            'port': 27017,
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that `host` and `port` are now childs of `CLIENT`.

More information can be found in the [Djongo documentation](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/integrating-django-with-mongodb/).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was simply list all the containers with

```
docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID        
q624462b055d        
f9324d078256        
r0888c63d21d        
tf5a32702bee        
e68d1ae9b74c
```

and delete the mongodb related ones using their IDs

```
docker rm q624462b055d f9324d078256
```

and change the host and port in the docker-compose file with

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'mongo,',
        'HOST': 'mongo',
        'PORT': 27017,
    }
}
```