# Connection refused to mongodb after running docker compose up

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi

I am getting the following error after running docker compose up and going in 0.0.0..:8000/docs to use a get method, in a fastapi project,[image]

The .env file content

```
MONGODB_URL = mongodb://localhost:27017/

MONGO_HOST = "0.0.0.0"
MONGO_PORT = 27017
MONGO_USER = ""
MONGO_PASS = ""
DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase"
TEST1_COLLECTION="TEST1_COLLECTION"
TEST2_COLLECTION="TEST2_COLLECTION"
TEST3_COLLECTION="TEST3_COLLECTION"
```

The Dockerfile content:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.9
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt 
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /app/requirements.txt
COPY ./app /app/app
WORKDIR /app/app/
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

The docker-compose.yml content

```
version: "3.9"
services:
 app:
  build: .
  command: uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  depends_on:
  - db
 db:
   image: mongo
   ports:
     - "27017:27017"
   volumes:
     - ./data:/data/db
```

What am I doing wrong, cause I just need to use the environment variables in docker and run the application?

Comment: Do you really use an empty password and username or did you just removed it for the question?

Comment: `mongodb://db:27017/` ? `localhost` refers to inside the container, you need to reference the other running container over docker's network.

Comment: You seem to have attached a hard-to-read PNG file in place of the error message; can you [edit] the question to include the text of the error instead?  The `MONGODB_URL=localhost` looks suspicious to me in that it will tell the `app` container to connect to itself and not the `db` container; see perhaps [pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111\] Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499438/pymongo-errors-serverselectiontimeouterror-localhost27017-errno-111-connect).

Answer (score 1):

I believe @MatsLindh might be right. You need to address the host of another container with running instance of MongoDB inside the Docker internal network (which is `db` container in your case).
Try using `MONGODB_URL = mongodb://db:27017/`

Answer (score 0):

add `container_name` to db service in docker-compose, and then use it's name as host when connecting to in python code.

eg.

```
mongodb://root:example@container_name:27017/?authMechanism=DEFAULT
```