# How to connect to Mongo inside a Docker container using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, docker

I pulled the official mongo image from the Docker website and started a mongo container named `dataiomongo`.

I now want to connect to the mongodb inside the container using pymongo.

This is the python script I wrote:

```
from pprint import pprint
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', port=27017)

db = client.admin

server = db.command("serverStatus")
pprint(server)
```

The error that came is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/dataio/test_mongo.py", line 8, in <module>
    server = db.command("serverStatus")
  File "D:\dataio\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 655, in command
    read_preference) as (sock_info, slave_ok):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "D:\dataio\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1135, in _socket_for_reads
    server = topology.select_server(read_preference)
  File "D:\dataio\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 226, in select_server
    address))
  File "D:\dataio\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 184, in select_servers
    selector, server_timeout, address)
  File "D:\dataio\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 200, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

How do I go about connecting to the mongodb inside the docker container?

Comment: how did you run the mogno container?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## run mongo

First you need to run mongo

```
$ docker run --rm --name my-mongo -it -p 27017:27017 mongo:latest
```

## as a daemon

```
$ docker run --name my-mongo -d mongo:latest
```

## connect to the previous container.. with another container

```
$ docker run -it --link my-mongo:mongo --rm mongo:latest sh -c 'exec mongo "$MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR:$MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT/test"'
```

## Insert Data into db

```
Insert the data into the db
```

### Connect db with python

```
client = MongoClient()
client.server_info()
db = client.yourdbname
```

Comment: Is there a simple equivalent for wrapping the docker commands up into a simple docker-compose file?

Answer (score 3):

I think you miss `-p 27017:27017` flag.
`docker run -p 27017:27017 --name mymongo -d mongo` .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you bind the 27017 container port to host port via -p 27017:27017 flag.