# How to connect to Mongo Container from another Docker Container using PyMongo and Docker Compose

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, pymongo

I'm new to Docker and Docker Compose and try to connect to MongoDB from a Docker container. I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128397/how-to-connect-to-mongo-inside-a-docker-container-using-pymongo) post, but it helped me not so much because the Docker Compose part is missing.

This is my project structure and I'm on Windows:

```
docker-compose.yml
backend
|-Dockerfile
|-test.py
```

The docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  backend:
    build: 
      context: backend
    command: ["python3", "test.py"]
    environment:
      MONGODB_DATABASE: db
      MONGODB_HOSTNAME: mongodb
    links:
      - mongo:mongo
```

The Dockerfile is this:

```
FROM python:latest

RUN pip install pymongo==3.11.1

COPY test.py .
CMD ["python", "test.py"]
```

And my Python script is this:

```
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://' + os.environ['MONGODB_HOSTNAME'] + \
                     ':27017/' + os.environ['MONGODB_DATABASE'])

db = client['data_db']
collection = db['data_collection']

data = {'name': 'John'}

collection.insert_one(data)
print(collection)
```

The script is running until I want to insert the data. I have played around a lot, but every time after 30 seconds I got this error message:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongodb:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6388d69c6a3630f8d93007d2, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('mongodb', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongodb:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')>]>
```

I appreciate any help. :)

Comment: Your MongoDB container is named `mongo`, but you've set `MONGODB_HOSTNAME` to `mongodb`.  These need to match. (You should probably also remove the obsolete `links:` block.)

Comment: Thank you, that's it! I removed the links-block too.