# Mongodb pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s,

Tags: python, mongodb, localhost, pymongo

I am trying to locally connect to my db. I've established a connection to the database on MongoDB Compass, but when I run my simple code, I get this error:

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno
> 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description:
> <TopologyDescription id: 60e2b31fab1da2bb146bb38c, topology_type:
> Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type:
> Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111]
> Connection refused')>]>
> root@LAPTOP-8OKVP35I:/portfolio/myProjects/webDevelopment/shopify_db#

This is the code I am running:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client["Shopper_Info"]
my_collection = db["Names"]
shopper_data = {'name': 'Yoni', 'email': 'test@gmail.com'}

my_collection.insert_one(shopper_data)

results= collection.find({"name": 'Yoni'})

for result in results:
print(result)
```

Comment: What is the connection string you use for the connection via Compass?

Comment: mongodb://localhost:27017

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pymongo keeps refusing the connection at 27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744147/pymongo-keeps-refusing-the-connection-at-27017)

Comment: Well no, because when I run those commands involving /var/lib/mongodb.lock  it says no such file or directory. When attempting to restart the service with their command, it says no service found

Comment: That solution is platform-dependent, but the generic process is the same: clean up lock file, restart mongod. Which platform are you running this on and how do you normally start mongod?

Comment: Using Ubuntu. I start Mogod by opening the application (MongoDB Compass)

Comment: MongoDB Compass is a client, not a server, it does not start the server, it merely connects to it. This solution suggests restarting the server, which on Ubuntu should be the `mongod` process and can be found with the command `ps aux | grep mongod`

Comment: Understood. I ran that command and then ran the file. Still got the same error

Answer (score 2):

This problem was also happening in my stack, I had my connection string in an env file to connect to mongo atlas.

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb://<username>:<password>@cluster-details
```

But the right way to do this is

```
MONGO_URI="mongodb://<username>:<password>@cluster-details"
```

Answer (score 1):

This happend to me as well.
make sure that you have started the mongod server.that worked for me.

```
sudo service mongod start.
```

Answer (score 1):

just add the above code to your settings.py in django :-

```
DATABASE = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'djongo',
 "CLIENT": {
           "name": <your_database_name>,
           "host": <your_connection_string>,
           "username": <your_database_username>,
           "password": <your_database_password>,
           "authMechanism": "SCRAM-SHA-1",
        },
    }
}
```

> but in host you may get this issue
> :-"pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError:"[SSL:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get
> local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997) so for this you add like :-
> "mongodb+srv://sampleUser:samplePassword@cluster0-gbdot.mongodb.net/sampleDB??ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE&retryWrites=true&w=majority"