# Python pymongo keeps refusing [Errno111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I tried to connect to MongoDB used pymongo. the log that comes out when print(db) is written was informed that the connection became normal.

```
// print(db) result
Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'dbsparta')
```

But when i used to CURD method (ex : insertOne) -> [Errno 111] error occured...

```
// My Code
from pymongo import MongoClient 
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)  
db = client.localdb 

print(db)

db.users.insert_one({'name':'bobby','age':21})
db.users.insert_one({'name':'kay','age':27})
db.users.insert_one({'name':'john','age':30})
```

Err Message

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ek3434/Project/TIL/SWJungle/jungle.py", line 11, in <module>
    db.users.insert_one({'name':'bobby','age':21})
  File "/home/ek3434/Project/TIL/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 705, in insert_one
    self._insert(document,
  File "/home/ek3434/Project/TIL/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 620, in _insert
    return self._insert_one(
  File "/home/ek3434/Project/TIL/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 609, in _insert_one
    self.__database.client._retryable_write(
  File "/home/ek3434/Project/TIL/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1551, in _retryable_write
    with self._tmp_session(session) as s:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/ek3434/Project/TIL/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1948, in _tmp_session
    s = self._ensure_session(session)
  File "/home/ek3434/Project/TIL/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1935, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "/home/ek3434/Project/TIL/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1883, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "/home/ek3434/Project/TIL/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1921, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "/home/ek3434/Project/TIL/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 520, in get_server_session
    session_timeout = self._check_session_support()
  File "/home/ek3434/Project/TIL/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 499, in _check_session_support
    self._select_servers_loop(
  File "/home/ek3434/Project/TIL/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 218, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 614ae9c2b0ed5823d0a5f151, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
```

I've tried the way that comes out on this link([Pymongo keeps refusing the connection at 27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744147/pymongo-keeps-refusing-the-connection-at-27017))

Implementing the solution given in that link results in the following results. but dosen't solve anything

```
// solution
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
// err message
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock': No such file or directory
```

and

```
// solution
sudo service mongodb start
// error
 * Starting database mongod                     [fail]
```

How can i fix it? I can't do anything because this error hasn't been resolved... T_T plz help..

Comment: You have checked and found the status `database mongod [fail]`, how about to continue to find out the reason leading to `service mongodb` fail?

Comment: I think you're right. Thank you. I'll try it..